# Amazon S3 multiple byte range request

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, httprequest

Amazon supports a single byte range request

```
curl -I --range 100-599 http://s3.amazonaws.com/1000genomes/data/NA06984/alignment/NA06984.chrom11.ILLUMINA.bwa.CEU.low_coverage.20111114.bam
```

Response header from the above request correctly shows `Content-Length: 500`

However if you add another range

```
curl -I --range 100-599,700-800 http://s3.amazonaws.com/1000genomes/data/NA06984/alignment/NA06984.chrom11.ILLUMINA.bwa.CEU.low_coverage.20111114.bam
```

It ignores the range request and gives the content length of the whole file `Content-Length: 1274819234`

Does anyone know if amazon s3 supports multiple byte range requests? Or a workaround?

Comment: Amazon S3 doesn't support retrieving multiple ranges of data per GET request. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Answer (score 5):

According to the doc as well as api still Amazon S3 does not supports multiple byte range requests. 
Can you tell us the use-case ?

Comment: Not the author but I stumbled upon this problem as well. I use this to index into measurement data stored as a binary blob. This allows to download specific traces. With the lack of multi range support, each trace must be downloaded in a single requests which is kinda annoying.